# Same behaviour for size() vs .size() with string?

Tags: c++

Is there any difference in output behaviour between using `size(x)` instead of `x.size()`, where `x` is a `string` variable? Or it is just another alias?

Comment: No, have a look at the documentation for `std::size()`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size

Comment: What is size? Are you talking about the standard library? If so, have you read the manual to std::size for finding answers to your questions?

Comment: I'm confused. In what sense is this question lacking in details, or clarity? Yes, it's a very simple question, but please note that this is not a reason to close a question. I'm voting to reopen, unless someone has a valid reason to close this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) is:

> Returns the size of the given container `c` or array `array`.
>
> > 1-2) Returns c.size(), converted to the return type if necessary.
> >
> > ...

So calling `std::size(x)` and `x.size()` has the same effect, where `x` is a `std::string`.

(This function can also accept an array, but that's not relevant when it comes to a `std::string`).